# How to input multiple time-series data(wave) for RNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I made the simple RNN model to learn and fit the one wave file.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np


a, sr = librosa.load("A.wav",sr=22050)
rawdata = librosa.stft(a, n_fft=512,hop_length= 512 // 4, window='hann') #make fourier transfered A.wav data.
rawdata = rawdata.transpose() # [Frame,Freq] => [Freq,Frame]

input_len = 10 # the frame number for learning to make next one
input=[]
target=[]
for i in range(0, len(rawdata) - input_len): 
    input.append( rawdata[i:i+input_len] ) # frames
    target.append( rawdata[i+input_len] )  # one step forward frame for answer.
 
X = np.array(input)
Y = np.array(target)

#Separate 8:2 for training and test
x, val_x, y, val_y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=int(X.shape[0] * 0.2), shuffle=False)

n_hidden = 512
epoch = 100
model = Sequential()

model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden, input_shape=(input_len, n_in), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation="linear")) 
model.add(Dense(n_in, activation="linear"))

opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)

model.summary()

history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=epoch, batch_size=10,validation_data=(val_x, val_y))
```

OK it works fine.
It learns the one wave file `A.wav`

However how can I learn multiple wave files??

`B.wav` `C.wav`

For example,

If I use model.fit() multiple times for each wav, does this model remember the past learning??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, model does remember previous train during fit, you can use fit multiple times as well. but its better to use `model.train_on_batch` this is simple version of fit to be used on small batch of data.

you can also modify your code to add other wav file feature to data.

```py
# second way
input_len = 10 # the frame number for learning to make next one
input=[]
target=[]

for f in ['A.wav','B.wav','C.wav']:
  a, sr = librosa.load(f,sr=22050)
  rawdata = librosa.stft(a, n_fft=512,hop_length= 512 // 4, window='hann') #make fourier transfered A.wav data.
  rawdata = rawdata.transpose() # [Frame,Freq] => [Freq,Frame]

  for i in range(0, len(rawdata) - input_len): 
    input.append( rawdata[i:i+input_len] ) # frames
    target.append( rawdata[i+input_len] )  # one step forward frame for answer.
```

Comment: THank you very much, I tried and understood how it works.